# Make a rake task fail if system call return error

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a Rakefile that I use to automate some tasks in my project.

Inside some tasks, I call `system`, but, even if the process return an error,
task continues without any issue.

How can I avoid that? I want to make rake exit when some subprocess return an error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can evaluate the return value of [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system)

```
system('inexistent command') or exit!(1)
puts "This line is not reached"
```

Comment: oh, just that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`sh`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/FileUtils#sh-instance_method) is the Rake way to call a command. It will fail with a neat message. Compared with `system`, `sh` prints out the command as well.